# JQuery: Apply closest img alt to closest paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply the alt of the closest img to the closest `<p>`. I've tried using `$(event.target ).closest("p" ).html(imgAlt);`, no luck. 
**UPDATE**
Getting img alt is not the issue, i simply want to be able to use this with multiple divs.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".vgQues").mousemove(function() {
        var imgAlt = $(event.target).closest("img").prop('alt');
        //Not working
        //$(event.target ).closest("p" ).html(imgAlt);

        $(".vegQuesTitle").text(src);
        $(".vegQuesTitle").show("fade");
        console.log(src);
    });

    $(".vgQues").mouseleave(function() {

        $(".vegQuesTitle").hide("");
        console.log(imgAlt);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="media menu-media">
    <div class="media-left media-top col-xs-12 vgQues">
        <p class="vegQuesTitle" style="position:top:-10px; left:50px;"></p>

        <img src="img/topping_corn.jpg" alt="Corn">
        <img src="img/redonion.jpg" alt="Red Onions">
        <img src="img/gpep.jpg" alt="Green Peppers">
        <img src="img/topping_jhalpinos.jpg" alt="Chopped Jhalpinos">
        <img src="img/cilan.jpg" alt="Cilantro">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you read what `.closest()` actually does?  It finds the closet matching parent node.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to use use mouseenter event(because the value of `alt` changes only when you hover an image) on the `img` and then set the content of the `p` like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vgQues img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".vegQuesTitle").text(this.alt||'');
    $(".vegQuesTitle").show("fade");
  });

  $(".vgQues").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".vegQuesTitle").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media menu-media">
  <div class="media-left media-top col-xs-12 vgQues">
    <p class="vegQuesTitle" style="position:top:-10px; left:50px;"></p>

    <img src="img/topping_corn.jpg" alt="Corn">
    <img src="img/redonion.jpg" alt="Red Onions">
    <img src="img/gpep.jpg" alt="Green Peppers">
    <img src="img/topping_jhalpinos.jpg" alt="Chopped Jhalpinos">
    <img src="img/cilan.jpg" alt="Cilantro">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `mouseenter` on `img` and use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to get `vgQues` and find `vegQuesTitle` in it(as `vgQues` can be multiple having `vegQuesTitle` so it should be the closest one) like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vgQues img").mouseenter(function() {
    var $elem = $(this).closest('.vgQues ') // get parent, if multiple para's
                         .find(".vegQuesTitle")// find para       
    $elem.text(this.alt) // add img alt
         .show("fade"); // show
  });    
  $(".vgQues").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".vegQuesTitle") // find para
           .text("").hide(); // empty and hide
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".vgQues img").mouseenter(function() {
    var $elem = $(this).closest('.vgQues ') // get parent, if multiple para's
                         .find(".vegQuesTitle")// find para       
    $elem.text(this.alt) // add img alt
         .show("fade"); // show
  });    
  $(".vgQues").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".vegQuesTitle") // find para
           .text("").hide(); // empty and hide
  });
});
```

```css
.media{
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media menu-media">
    <div class="media-left media-top col-xs-12 vgQues">
        <p class="vegQuesTitle" style=""></p>

        <img src="img/topping_corn.jpg" alt="Corn">
        <img src="img/redonion.jpg" alt="Red Onions">
        <img src="img/gpep.jpg" alt="Green Peppers">
        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="media menu-media">
    <div class="media-left media-top col-xs-12 vgQues">
        <p class="vegQuesTitle" style=""></p>

        <img src="img/topping_jhalpinos.jpg" alt="Chopped Jhalpinos">
        <img src="img/cilan.jpg" alt="Cilantro">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this).find("img").prop('alt')` as `img` is child node not `vgQues`'s parent. The [`$.fn.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

However I think you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".vgQues img").hover(function() {
        var imgAlt = $(this).prop('alt');
        $(this).closest('.vgQues').find(".vegQuesTitle").text(imgAlt).show("fade");

    }, function() {
        $(this).closest('.vgQues').find(".vegQuesTitle").hide("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `attr` function in Jquery

Try this

```
var imgAlt =  $(event.target ).closest("img" ).attr('alt');
```

Let me know if it is helpful